# How to create a table inside a form with 100s of records using bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications

The user needs to *approve* and if he wishes *reject* some records.For this I made 2 checkboxes (only 1 can be selected ) per record (row) in a table inside a **form** .Records also have a field of "comment" which can have very long texts with multiple lines.

Problems I am facing (I fix one and something else breaks)

1) How do I scroll the table vertically without hiding Column Names.
  I tried many approaches but that disturbs alignment of column names with       data in columns.

2)Since comment can contain many lines.How do I show it in table without overlaying content on other columns.
  I tried truncating the content with ellipses and showing the content on mouse hover but that also overlays comment text on nearby columns.

Following is the code it contains a banner, nav bar , panel > form > table + submit button

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="well well-sm"><H1 align="center">BANNER</H1></div>
        </div>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebApp</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/Page1">Page1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Page2">Page2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Page3">Page3</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="/Page4">Page4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Page5">Page5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>

        <div class="col-md-1"></div>

        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <form method="POST" action="/approve_2" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><H3 align="center" class="well well-sm">Approve Records</H3></div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value=Internet Explorer />
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden2" value=2 /> <input
                    type="hidden" name="hidden3" value=Internet Explorer />
                    <div class="panel-body" >

                        <div class="mytable">
                            <table class="table table-fixed">
                                <div class="myhead">
                                    <thead>

                                        <tr>
                                            <div class="col-md-1"><th>Approve</th></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-1"><th>Reject</th></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6"><th>Comment</th></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2"><th>Preview</th></div>
                                        </tr>

                                    </thead>
                                </div>
                                <div class="myrows">

                                    <tr>
                                        <div class="col-md-1">
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="records"
                                                id=1
                                                value=1
                                                onclick="document.getElementById('DEL_1').checked=false;"> 1
                                            </td>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-1">
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="toDelete" id=DEL_1
                                                value=1
                                                onclick="document.getElementById('1').checked=false;">1
                                            </td>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <td>hgalkjdfnvlkaudhglkajfauehfpausdihnvbvdfgaouerfyli</td>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <td >
                                                john@example.com
                                            </td>
                                        </div>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <div class="col-md-1">
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="records"
                                                id=2
                                                value=2
                                                onclick="document.getElementById('DEL_2').checked=false;"> 2
                                            </td>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-1">
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="toDelete" id=DEL_2
                                                value=1
                                                onclick="document.getElementById('2').checked=false;">2
                                            </td>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <td>hgalkjdfnvlkaudhglkajfauehfpausdihnvbvdfgaouerfyli</td>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <td >
                                                john@example.com
                                            </td>
                                        </div>
                                    </tr>

                                </div>
                            </table>

                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-5"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>


                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can remove alot of your headache if you can use Datatables Plugin. http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Also, you should validate your html. There are missing quotes where they shouldn't be missing, structural problems etc.

Comment: @Reddy

I checked the example on following link "http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_xy.html"
The only issue with this approach is if one of the column has many lines of text it will enlarge the whole column leading to horizontal scrolling.
How can I fix the column width or set limit to it.
(examples of only vertical scrolling have the same issue too)